# difference between functionName() and functionName.call() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hopefully the title is self explanatory, what is the advantage of using the .call() method in Javascript compared with just writing functionName(); ?

Comment: There is also functionName.apply(). See 15.5.4.3 and 15.5.4.4 in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`functionName.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) takes an object instance as its first parameter. It then runs `functionName` within the context of that object instance (ie "this" is the specified instance)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't pass anything into `call()`, it will be the same; the function will be run with the same scope that the call to `call()` is made:

```
function test() {
    alert(this);
}

test(); // alerts the window object
test.call(); // alerts the window object
```

But if you pass an object into `call()`, that object will be used as the scope:

```
test.call("hi"); // alerts "hi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me show an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var developerName = "window";
function test(){
   var developer = function(developerName ){ this.developerName  = developerName;}
    developer.prototype = {
      displayName : function(){alert(this.developerName );}
    }
    var developerA = new developer("developerA");
    var developerB = new developer("developerB");
    developerA.displayName();//will display an alert box with "developerA" as its inner text
    developerA.displayName.call();//will display an alert box with "window" as its inner text, in this case the context is the window object.
    developerA.displayName.call(developerB);//will display an alert box with "developerB" as its inner text
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="display names"/>
<body>
</html>
```

Further reading:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/getoutbindingsituations

Hope this helps.